# Backbone Marionette - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined

Tags: marionette

I know that the error is generated by jQuery. Is there any way I can structure a backbone.marionette application to avoid the below error?

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined`

The error occurs because I create a Layout, which has regions. In the onRender function I load  a collection and execute fetch. When the fetch is complete, I populate the region. If I switch to a different view, the error is triggered because of self.content.show which no longer exists.

```
var view = Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: _.template(tplPage),
    className: 'customers-view',
    regions:{
        content: '.customers-content'
    },

    onRender: function(){
        var self = this,
            colCustomers = new ColCustomers();

        colCustomers.fetch({success: function(){
            self.content.show(new ViewCustomersList({collection: colCustomers}));
        }});
    }
});
```

NOTE: At the moment I wrap self.content.show() in a try catch and its working. Ideally I avoid that.

Comment: The code you included should work fine. Is there anything else going on that isn't included? You say the error is being generated by `jQuery`. What do you mean by that? Is `typeof self.content != "undefined"`? Also, if wrapping that function in a try catch is working that means you are probably calling the success function multiple times. Are you doing something somewhere else that renders this view multiple times?

Comment: The exception is thrown when I change the view. The above code is a parent view that will then populate the `content` region. If I browse to a different view while the fetch is still ongoing, the DOM element `.customers-content` is removed since the parent view is changed. Therefore once the fetch is complete, the success function will execute but self.content is now undefined. Only way I manage to solve it is to catch the exception. I was wondering if anyone structured their code in any other way that avoids the try catch

Comment: Ah. Yeah I understand your issue now. I'll add an answer below that shows how to handle that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `onRender` function and listen for the fetch differently.

```
onRender: function(){
  var colCustomers = new ColCustomers();
  this.listenTo(colCustomers, "sync", function () {
    this.content.show(new ViewCustomersList({collection: colCustomers}));
  });
  colCustomers.fetch();
}
```

What I did was change the approach to binding the event listener. By using the [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) function from `Backbone.Events`, you get handlers that are cleaned up for free when the listener object dies.